# Unable to move from JQuery.live() to JQuery.on()

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-selectors

I am loading some html via $.get() into a Jquery-dialog-popup.

Upon clicking a link in the newly inserted html some function should be triggered.

This works with live() but NOT with on().

This works:

```
$(".remove").live("click", function () {
  // enter ok
}
```

This does not:

```
$("div").on("click", ".remove", function () {
// or $("#delete").on("click", ".remove", function () {
// or $(".remove").on("click", function () {

      // never enters...
});
```

html:

```
<div id="delete">
  <a class="remove" href="#">link</a>
</div>
```

The on()-function works in case I am calling it directly from my main-template without loading the content into a dialog-window first via $.get.

Comment: May be a dumb question, but did you not forget to add a closing parens at your `on` call?

Comment: copy-paste error, thanks for the hint but unfortunately that's not it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To pre-bind events for dynamic content, they have to be bound to a pre-existing element.

So, if the `<div id="delete">` is part of the dynamic content, then you shouldn't use it to bind the event. You can, however, bind to the container that the dynamic content is loaded into.

So, if the resulting HTML is:

```
<div id="contents">
  <!-- start template -->

  <div id="delete">
    <a class="remove" href="#">link</a>
  </div>

  <!-- end template -->
</div>
```

Then, your JavaScript can be:

```
$('#contents').on('click', 'div a.remove', function () {
  // ...
});
```

[`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) uses `document` for this -- an element that exists until reload or redirect -- making the following lines equivalent:

```
$("a.remove").live("click", function () { /* ... */ });
$(document).on("click", "a.remove", function () { /* ... */ });
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't see the whole code but I would bet that you're not putting the

```
$("div").on("click", ".remove", function () {
// or $("#delete").on("click", ".remove", function () {
// or $(".remove").on("click", function () {

      // never enters...
}
```

part ONCE the new code has been inserted into the DOM.

You need to attach the event listeners to the new elements created. Live works because it works for existing and future elements like that.

**EDIT:**

If you want the click handler to work for an element that gets loaded dynamically, then you need to set the event handler on a parent object (that does not get loaded dynamically) and give it a selector that matches your dynamic object like this:

```
$('#parent').on("click", ".remove", function() {});
```

Comment: That's my problem, I guess, how do I make on() aware of future-insertions?

Comment: You can't. You have to call to .on on the success part of the $.get or use live. Why would you stick to on?

Comment: As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated, so it's impossible with on() ?